# Clang can't find cinttypes after fresh Ubuntu Install

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clang++

Just as the title says. This is a fresh Ubuntu install, and while g++ compiles my code no problem, clang++ tells me it can't find cinttypes
Any fixes ?

Edit: As asked, here's the output of `echo | clang -E -dM -xc++ - | egrep __cplusplus` : `#define __cplusplus 201402L`

Edit: Here's a minimal reproducible example, followed by the error message:

```
#include <cinttypes>
int main() { return 0;}
```

> clang++ test.cpp

```
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'cinttypes' file not found
#include <cinttypes>
```

And no error when trying to compile with `g++`

Comment: Include path setup maybe?

Comment: `cinttypes` requires `c++11`.  What's the default language standard assumed by your `clang++` installation (although I find it hard to believe it's  anything less than `c++11`).  Please [edit] your question to show the output of `echo | clang -E -dM -xc++ - | egrep __cplusplus`.

Comment: Please provide the code -- preferably as a [mcve] -- and error message(s) as text verbatim.

Comment: I've provided both of these

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this with `sudo apt install libc++abi-dev libstdc++-dev`